# Trying to implement a swipeable week view just like Apple Calendar default app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, calendar, swipe-gesture

I want to have something similar to the default Apple Calendar week view. When swiping to the next/previous week, the action is looking like a scroll but I personally don't think they are holding all these weeks in the memory.. Also the week is always centered after ending scroll action.

How can I update to display the previous/next week days when swiping/dragging from that week view?

So this is my HomeTabView.

```
struct HomeTabView: View {
@Namespace var animation

@EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
@EnvironmentObject var dateModel: DateModel

init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
}

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                Section {
                    //MARK: - Week View
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(spacing: 4) {
                            ForEach(dateModel.currentWeek, id: \.self) { day in
                                VStack() {
                                    Text(dateModel.extractDate(date: day, format: "dd"))
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    Text(dateModel.extractDate(date: day, format: "EE"))
                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(dateModel.isToday(date: day) ? .white : .black)
                                        .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
                                        .opacity(workoutManager.hasWorkouts(for: dateModel.extractDate(date: day, format: "dd/MM/yyy")) ? 1 : 0)
                                }
                                .foregroundStyle(dateModel.isToday(date: day) ? .primary : .tertiary)
                                .foregroundColor(dateModel.isToday(date: day) ? .white : .black)
                                .frame(width: (geometry.size.width - 32) / 7, height: geometry.size.width / 7 * 1.5)
                                .background (
                                    ZStack {
                                        if dateModel.isToday(date: day) {
                                            Capsule()
                                                .fill(.black)
                                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "CURRENTDAY", in: animation)
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                                .contentShape(Capsule())
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        dateModel.currentDay = day
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width)
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { parentGeometry in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color(UIColor.systemGray2))
                                    .frame(width: parentGeometry.size.width, height: 0.5)
                                    .position(x: parentGeometry.size.width / 2, y: parentGeometry.size.height)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    WorkoutsView()
                } header: {
                    HeaderView()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .clipped()
}
```

}

Currently the week view is implemented as a HStack in a ScrollView, but I personally have no idea how to handle the implementation using these 2.

DateModel is responsible for keeping track of current week days and current day while WorkoutManager is handling the workouts while holding them in a [String: [Workout]] type dictionary. The key is date formatted like "25/05/2022" (tried to use Date type as key but as far as I know this is not Hashable and have no idea how to make it hashable, while Workout struct has only a title for now.

[Home tab as seen while not swiping through week view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxqGl.png)
[Current scroll/swipe/drag gesture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFKm5.png)

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to take help from third party library CalendarKit or you can integrate the same directly into your project. [CalendarKit](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit)

I hope this would work out for your objective.